# gorm db.Clauses(clause.OnConflict{UpdateAll: true}).Create(&user), when conflict, why user.CreatedAt doesn't conform to the corresponding record?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

As the gorm documentation says, the code below updates all columns, except primary keys, to new value on conflict

```
db.Clauses(clause.OnConflict{
  UpdateAll: true,
}).Create(&user)
```

I find that when user.ID exists in the database, which means conflict occurs, all the columns except "created_at" get updated. I can understand this behavior because what we did is updating. However, the struct user does not conform to the record in the database. Its `CreatedAt` property is same as its `UpdatedAt` property, but not same as the "created_at" column in the database which was not changed. This causes a discrepancy between the data stored in struct user and the record in users relation. Why is this and how can I solve this discrepancy?